# HTML select box with images using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to create an HTML drop down that will display flags of countries.
The only solutions i found was with jquery and it generated a  list of links from a select box.

The problem is i don't want to link the user to a different page , i want to later use the selected value on form submit (like a simple select box)

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What about this: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown. It seems to do what you want. Number 1 result when I look in Google for `jquery image dropdown` by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this plugin in the past - hopefully it does the trick for you (unless it's one you've already tried):

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: I have downloaded manually using view source - and it is exactly what i need .... Thanks .

Comment: this plugin is no longer working with the latest version of jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value you need from the jquery control and put it in a hidden field in the form you want to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(".myFlagItem").click(function() {
    $(".myHiddenInputBox").val($(this).attr("flagValue"));
})
```